# Shell script: spawn a terminal running a command, with the ability to suspend/resume job within the newely spawned terminal

Tags: bash, shell, background-foreground, job-control

I would like to use a shell-script or shell-command to spawn/open a new terminal, and immediately run a command in it. However, it should also give me the ability to suspend and later resume the command/program that the new terminal is running.

When I try to do this, I am able to spawn the new terminal with the program running in it, but whenever I try to suspend it, the terminal hangs.

Essentially, my use case is to run a script that opens a text file for editing in `nano`, with the ability to suspend nano, as you can normally do if it were launched interactively from a shell and not via a script.

I searched a lot, but I never found a solution.

I tried many things, but always failed. Without shell-script, what I do is to spawn xterm, `cd` to the folder containing `file.txt` and then issue `nano file.txt` in the terminal. Nano opens to edit the file, and I am able to suspend it (`^T^Z`), do whatever I need to do, and resume it once I am done.

However, if I run it via a script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e "nano file.txt"
```

nano opens fine, but if I try to suspend it (`^T^Z`), the terminal hangs.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like you are looking for something which lets you use a pseudo-TTY, like Expect.

Comment: I don't use `nano`, so I'm not sure what you expect when you suspend.  If you're expecting a shell prompt in the terminal then no, you won't get one by "suspending" in the sense of that term I recognize, because there is no shell running in the terminal.  You're running `nano` in it *instead of* a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set job control with `set -m`:

```
xterm -e bash --rcfile <(echo 'set -m; nano file.txt')
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!! Thanks! I knew about and tried to use the "set -m" option, but never succeeded. I must have been calling it incorrectly.